# What do I replace IUnityContainer.Registrations.ToList() with?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, unity-container, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I was recently given an application to support.  It was in MVC3 using NHibernate and Unity along with a host of other packages.  In upgrading to MVC5, I update all the packages to their latest version.  The problem now is that Unity dropped a couple of properties/methods from the IUnityContainer.  I am wondering how do I replace these lines of codes to get my code to compile again?

```
IUnityContainer.Registrations.ToList()
```

and

```
IUnityContainer.IsRegistered(serviceType)
```

IUnityContainer of course is defined as an IUnityContainer object and I am not trying to use the type directly.

I cannot find anything online about what to replace these with.  I see from Microsoft that these methods have been deprecated, but no reason why they have been deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MVC 5, I recommend using [Unity 3.5](https://unity.codeplex.com/). This was the stable release available with MVC 5. You should be able to get it by using Nuget prompt.

Unity 4 looks still under work to me, and is lacking a migration guide. See [here](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity/issues/20).

Comment: This worked for me.  It's an interesting paradox how most developers hate to do documentation, but want others to document their code!

Comment: I have to say I am bit uncomfortable with Asp.Net Core and related moves to open-source. One year after VS 2015 release, while those frameworks were supposed to be the choice for VS 2015, they are still RC. And they have many breaking changes, [some of them](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/pull/3039) looking to me superfluous. About doc, if there is a single thing to document with releases, this is breaking changes. It is quite repelling not to have them with releases notes.